# Destacar parte do eixo X em gráfico do Matplotlib/Pyplot/Python3

Tags: python-3.x, gráfico, matplotlib, plot

Olá.

Estou montando um gráfico de linhas de receitas e despesas por ano e gostaria de destacar apenas os anos de 2020 e 2021 (referentes à pandemia de COVID-19) de forma que o fundo de todo o gráfico nesses anos tenha uma coloração diferente.

Os dados estão em um data frame do Pandas com os campos ANO, VL_ARRECADADO e VL_EMENHADO.

O gráfico é construído com matplotlib.pyplot e Python 3.

Gostaria de algo parecido com isso:

[image: Exemplo de como o gráfico deve se parecer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito pesquisar na documentação da API do Matplotlib, encontrei a solução em [matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()

plt.axvspan(xmin=1.5, xmax=1.75, ymin=0, ymax=2, color='#d9d9d9', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Isso irá gerar o seguinte gráfico:
[image: Exemplo de gráfico]

A linha `plt.axvspan(xmin=1.5, xmax=1.75, ymin=0, ymax=2, color='#d9d9d9', alpha=0.5)` é quem adiciona a faixa vertical cinza.